# Product of averages

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, products, holder-inequality

Let $(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $(y_1,...,y_n)$ be two different tuples of positive reals such that $x_1\times\dots\times x_n=y_1\times\dots\times y_n = c$.
Is it true that
$$\left(\frac{x_1+y_1}{2}\right)\times\cdots\times \left(\frac{x_n+y_n}{2}\right) > c?$$

I think this should follow from a concavity argument, perhaps on the function $f(x_1,...,x_n) = x_1\times\cdots\times x_n$, but not sure how exactly.

Comment: $\frac{x_k+y_k}{2} \ge \sqrt{x_k y_k}$, so ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) states that $\frac{x+y}{2} \ge \sqrt{x y}$ for $x, y \ge 0$, with equality if and only if $x=y$.

It follows that
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k+y_k}{2} \ge \prod_{k=1}^n  \sqrt{x_k y_k}
= \sqrt{\prod_{k=1}^n x_k \cdot \prod_{k=1}^n y_k} = c 
$$
with equality if and only if $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$.

If you want to use a concavity argument then consider
$$
 g(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \log x_1 + \ldots + \log x_n \, .
$$
$g$ is concave as a sum of concave functions.

Answer (score 2):

By Holder
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k+y_k}{2}\geq\frac{\left(\sqrt[n]{\prod\limits_{k=1}^nx_k}+\sqrt[n]{\prod\limits_{k=1}^ny_k}\right)^n}{2^n}=c$$

Comment: Without the proof?

Comment: @nilo de roock It's the proof. What is your question? I am ready to explain.

Comment: What do you mean by "By Holder"?

Comment: About Holder see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/5773 I used Holder for $n$ sequences: $(x_k,y_k)$

Comment: OK. Got it. Thank you.